# Run function when Stripe Checkout is successful

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, stripe-payments

In my Nodejs/Express API, I want to run a set of conformation code after the client is successfully checked out in Stripe.

This is my checkout function which basically processes the checkout phase:

```
// Checkout
const checkoutCart = async (req, res, next) => {
  const cart_id = req.params.cart_id;
  const user_id = req.user.user_id;

  try {
    // Check if cart isn't empty
    const cart = await db.query(selectCartProducts, [user_id]);
    if (!cart.rows.length) {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Cart Is Empty" });
    } else {
      // Calculate the total price of the products based on their quantity
      const total_price = cart.rows
        .reduce((acc, item) => {
          return acc + parseFloat(item.price) * item.quantity;
        }, 0)
        .toFixed(2);

      // Check if shipping address has been provided in the user info
      const address = await db.query(checkAddress, [user_id]);
      if (!address.rows.length) {
        missingAddressError(next);
      } else {

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Stripe
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          line_items: cart.rows.map((product) => {
            return {
              price_data: {
                currency: "usd",
                product_data: {
                  name: product.name,
                  images: product.img_urls,
                },
                unit_amount: product.price * 100,
              },
              quantity: product.quantity,
            };
          }),
          mode: "payment",
          success_url: process.env.ADDRESS1,
          cancel_url: process.env.ADDRESS2,
        });

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // I want the below code to run if the checkout is a success
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Create new order
        const order = await db.query(insertOrder, [
          user_id,
          total_price,
          "Complete",
        ]);
        const order_id = order.rows[0].order_id;

        // Move products from cart to order history
        await Promise.all(
          cart.rows.map(async (product) => {
            await db.query(insertProductIntoOrder, [
              order_id,
              product.product_id,
              product.quantity,
              product.color,
            ]);
            // Delete products from cart after adding them to order history (empty cart)
            await db.query(deleteProductFromCart, [
              cart_id,
              product.product_id,
            ]);
          })
        );

        res.status(201).json({
          message: "Order Submitted Successfully",
          order: {
            order_number: order.rows[0].order_number,
            total_price: order.rows[0].total_price,
            status: order.rows[0].status,
          },
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Is there any way I can check the status of Stripe Checkout and do other stuff according to the result of it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Stripe webhook events for this. More specifically, listen to the `checkout.session.completed` event to run your code.

Stripe has a documentation page covering this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have implemented the webhook events but I have no idea how I can set it as a middleware that would run after `checkout.session.completed` event.

Comment: @Nima if you are still stuck, you need to use the [stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli) to forward the successful payment to your local webhook. in prod, you use your stripe dashboard to forward to your webhook